# Solving $u_t=4u_{xx}+\sin{(\pi x)}+\sin{(2\pi x)}$ using an eigenfunction expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I would like to solve
$\begin{cases} u_t=4u_{xx}+\sin{(\pi x)}+\sin{(2\pi x)} & 0<x<1, t>0 \\ u(0,t)=0 \\ u(1,t)=0 \\ u(x,0)=0\end{cases}\tag*{}$
using an eigenfunction expansion.

**My attempt:**

By solving an eigenvalue problem
$\begin{cases} \phi''(x) = \lambda \phi (x), 0<x<1 \\ \phi (0)=0 \\ \phi (1)=0\end{cases}\tag*{}$

we obtain that the solution is $\phi_n(x)=B_n \sin{n\pi x}$($B_n$:constant) and the corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda = -n^2\pi^2$. Here $n=1,2,3,\cdots$.

So we perform the eigenfunction expansion and we have
$\displaystyle u(x,t) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(t)\sin{n\pi x}\tag*{}$
where $c_n(t)$ is a function of $t$. This $c_n$ satisfies, by initial condition,
$\displaystyle u(x,0) = 0 =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(0)\sin{n\pi x}\tag*{}$
Therefore $c_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.

Now substitute the expansion to the PDE:
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dot{c_n}(t)\sin{n\pi x}  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-4n^2\pi^2)c_n(t)\sin{n\pi x}+\sin{(\pi x)}+\sin{(2\pi x)}\tag*{}$

This means
$\dot{c_n}(t) = \begin{cases} -4n^2\pi^2 c_n(t) & n\neq 1,2 \\ (1-4\pi^2)c_1(t) & n=1 \\  (1-16\pi^2)c_2(t) & n=2 \end{cases} \tag*{}$

Solve this and we get
$c_n(t) = \begin{cases} A_ne^{-4n^2\pi^2t} & n\neq 1,2 \\ A_1e^{(1-4\pi^2)t} & n=1 \\  A_2e^{(1-16\pi^2)t} & n=2 \end{cases} \tag*{}$

For some constant $A_n$.

However, by the initial condition, $A_n=c_n(0)=0$. This leads to $u(x,t)=0$. But it obviously does not satisfy the PDE.

---

What went wrong in the solution? I suspect there is a typo in the problem. For reference, here is the original problem:

[image: https://gyazo.com/575d464985c42c1e50efdff592c98cdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equations for $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$ should be
\begin{align*} 
\dot{c_1} & = -4\pi^2c_1 + 1 \\ 
\dot{c_2} & = -16\pi^2c_2 + 1
\end{align*}